# How do I add zone based alternates for ContainerWidgets in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I'd like to be able to customize how lists are rendered by `ContainerWidget`s. Shape tracing only gives me the following options:

1. Parts.ContainerWidget.cshtml
2. Parts.ContainerWidget-url-homepage.cshtml

I'd like to be able to supply an alternate for a specific zone. I *think* that `IShapeTableProvider` is the way to go, but I'm just not sure. I've also thought of using a Widget alternate (`Widget-MyZone.cshtml`) but I can't understand how to get to the underlying list items to render them myself. Also, overriding Widget seems like overkill. Ideally, I'd like to be able to add a Part alternate like `Parts.ContainerWidget-MyZone.cshtml`.

There seem to be quite a few posts around the web that discuss this problem, but nothing I could find really points to a concrete working example.

Is this the right approach? Something else I should try? Any examples around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Orchard 1.4 has built-in support for zone based container widget alternates. The recommended solution, therefore, is to just upgrade to 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

IShapeTable provider should work. What happens when you try it? Here's a rough example (not tested):

```
public class Shapes : IShapeTableProvider {
    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder) {
        builder.Describe("Content").OnDisplaying(displaying => {

                if (displaying.ShapeMetadata.DisplayType == "Detail"
                    && (displaying.Shape.ContentItem as ContentItem).ContentType.Equals("MyWidgetType", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {

                    var metadata = displaying.ShapeMetadata;
                    ContentItem contentItem = displaying.Shape.ContentItem;
                    metadata.Alternates.Add("MyWidgetType_MyCUstomAlternate");
                }

            });



    }
```

Comment: I've created a simple shape table provider (http://pastebin.com/NwiYqh6a) and put it in a "Code" folder in my theme, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Shape tracing doesn't show any additional alternates for the Parts_ContainerWidget.

Comment: On a related note, is there any documentation for shape table providers (how to use one, what they can do, etc.)?

Comment: Try enabling the "WidgetAlternates" and "UrlAlternates" modules if you haven't already.

Comment: Yes, some here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates. Also useful: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/01/10/orchard-shapeshifting.aspx, and http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/customizing-orchard-shapes#.T1Tm-BmgA64

Comment: Both WidgetAlternates and UrlAlternates are enabled, but still no effect from the shape table provider. Anything else that might be going wrong? I guess I should just try a fresh deployment instead.

Comment: I just installed Orchard 1.4 and it appears it has zone based alternates for container widgets available out of the box. I'm just going to use 1.4 now instead of 1.3 which I was using earlier.

Comment: Nice -- glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Ragesh: you should post your "switch to 1.4" solution and accept it. I'm sure you won't be alone with that question